# Flutter Qr_Code_Scanner 404, No barcode scanner found ios

Tags: flutter, qr-code, flutter-qrcode

I'm using the qr_code_scanner package and getting an error like this on ios.

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: CameraException(404, No barcode scanner found)
#0 QRViewController.resumeCamera
package:qr_code_scanner/src/qr_code_scanner.dart:304
<asynchronous suspension>
```

how can i solve this

Comment: check here : https://github.com/juliuscanute/qr_code_scanner/issues/557

Answer (score 0):

Use this
qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any buttons to close the QR scanner, then make sure to clear the controller like this.

```
 _controller = null;
```

I hope it'll help.